# Missing `System.Net.Http' error when I scrape

Tags: c#

I am trying to scrape the *New York Times* using the free https://repl.it/languages/csharp compiler.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class DownloadPageHttpClient
{
 static void Main()
 {
    Task t = new Task(DownloadPageAsync);
    t.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void DownloadPageAsync()
{
    string page = "http://www.nytimes.com";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
  }
}
```

I am almost certain that my code is correct, and I have included  using System.Net.Http, but I still get this error message:

```
main.cs(2,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Http' does not    exist in the namespace `System.Net'. Are you missing `System.Net.Http' assembly reference?
```

Comment: My guess would be that they have chosen not to include it for security reasons. Compiling on your own machine should work just fine.

Comment: I doubt they have all the assemblies. My guess is the assembly which `System.Net.Http` is not included so the compiler has no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: c# ain't good for scraping. You can use python or something

Comment: Could anyone please suggest a free on-line compiler that would do this job?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the fact that the online compiler that you are using does not have that library.

use  http://rextester.com/ that will do the trick.

Comment: When I try to run the script I get this error: "Entry method 'Main' in class 'Program' in namespace 'Rextester' not found" any suggestions?